# Change value in string to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In total of 8 columns I want to start from 3rd one and convert them to integer type. They are values buy in strings. ex: "1436", "12", etc.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,3:].astype(int)`

Comment: if I do astype(int) it gives me ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,439'

Comment: @h_musk cut the commas out before `int()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
df.iloc[:,3:].replace({',': ''},regex=True).astype(int)
```